# Merge 2 or more xmls with xslt by attribute value?

Tags: xml, xslt, filter, merge

I have the following xml:

```
<PCstore>
    <StoreList>
        <Store id="001">
            <ItemList>
                <Items laptop="DELL" price="300"/>
                <Items laptop="gateway" price="450"/>
                <Items screen="LG" price="200"/>
            </ItemList>
        </Store>
    </StoreList>
</PCstore>
```

I have to merge with:

```
<PCstore>
    <StoreList>
        <Store id="002">
            <ItemList>
                <Items laptop="gateway" price="650"/>
                <Items screen="LG" price="200/>
                <Items speakers="sony" price="50"/>
            </ItemList>
        </Store>
    </StoreList>
</PCstore>
```

And the desire output ifiltering the attribute (laptop="gateway"):

```
<PCstore>
    <StoreList>
        <Store id="001">
            <ItemList>
                <Items laptop="gateway" price="450"/>
            </ItemList>
        </Store>
        <Store id="002">
            <ItemList>
                <Items laptop="gateway" price="650"/>
            </ItemList>
        </Store>
    </StoreList>
</PCstore>
```

And so on for more xml3.xml, xml4.xml
etc...

I don't have the codes I tried, I'm kinda new on XSLT, i hope someone can assist me with this.

**UPDATE**:

I tried this code, but its not working...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Items">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="document('xml2.xml')
              /PCstore/StoreList/Store/ItemList[@id = current()/../@id]
                     /Items[@laptop = current()/@value]/*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is the number of files going to be limited to a certain number, or will there be an unlimited number? Also, will any of the different files contain the same store Id? If so, what would you expect to happen in such circumstances?

Comment: It's not supposed to have the same store.
For the limit, lets say I'll have around 20 xmls that i have to merge, but if i can get at least 2 xmls merged would be great, after I guess only I have to apply the same xsl to the output and a new xml.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can only use XSLT1.0, one way to do this would be to pass the list of xml files as a parameter to your XSLT. For example:

```
<xsl:param name="filelist">
   <files>
      <file>xml2.xml</file>
      <!-- We can place here xml3.xml and so on -->
   </files>
</xsl:param>
```

(So, in this case, I am assuming you apply the XSLT to the first xml1.xml, and you only pass in any other files as parameters).

However, in XSLT1.0 you will need to make use of an extension function to process this parameter as a node-set. Doing `<xsl:for-each select="$filelist/files/file">` will result in the error "*Reference to variable or parameter 'files' must evaluate to a node list.*". Therefore you will need to use an extension function to convert it into a [node-set](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html). In my example, I will be using Microsoft's one in my example, but depending on your platform, you might use exslt.org/common

Here is the full XSLT in this case

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
     extension-element-prefixes="msxml">

   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:param name="filelist">
      <files>
         <file>xml2.xml</file>
      </files>
   </xsl:param>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="StoreList">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
         <xsl:for-each select="msxml:node-set($filelist)/files/file">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document(text())/PCstore/StoreList/Store"/>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Items[not(@laptop='gateway')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XSLT the following it output

```
<PCstore>
   <StoreList>
      <Store id="001">
         <ItemList>
            <Items laptop="gateway" price="450"/>
         </ItemList>
      </Store>
      <Store id="002">
         <ItemList>
            <Items laptop="gateway" price="650"/>
         </ItemList>
      </Store>
   </StoreList>
</PCstore>
```

Do note, the files must exist for this to work. If you pass in the name of a file that does not exist, an error will occur.

Comment: Thanks, I applied this option and worked perfect, I just can appreciate your time and work for this solution, I think you saved me for a while, I still have some changes to do.

Thanks Tim!!
Any way to contact you if I require some help?

Comment: Hi, how am I able to send the list of params to the xsl, the file list in this case?
And the "brand" list if possible? (to generate the filter)

Comment: That depends on what platform/language you are using (php, asp, c#, for example). If you can't work it out, then feel free to ask a whole new question here on StackOverflow, and someone will be able to help you out!

Comment: Thanks, I'm working just with windows environment, I'm "merging/converting" the xmls with vbs transform, I'm going to create a .bat to run from console, so I'm wondering how to send the values i need to filter and the files to be merged.
Thats all, THANKS!!! I'll give you upvote as soon as I can.

Comment: If there's no Items = gateway in stock, how can I aboid showing the Store in the xml?, thanks.

Comment: You could add the following template: `<xsl:template match="Store[not(ItemList/Items/@laptop='gateway')]"/>`

Comment: Thanks!, how can I know that kind of "coding", study xPath? avoid*

Answer (score 0):

If you can use XSLT 2.0, you can use `collection()`...

**xml1.xml**

```
<PCstore>
    <StoreList>
        <Store id="001">
            <ItemList>
                <Items laptop="DELL" price="300"/>
                <Items laptop="gateway" price="450"/>
                <Items screen="LG" price="200"/>
            </ItemList>
        </Store>
    </StoreList>
</PCstore>
```

**xml2.xml**

```
<PCstore>
    <StoreList>
        <Store id="002">
            <ItemList>
                <Items laptop="gateway" price="650"/>
                <Items screen="LG" price="200"/>
                <Items speakers="sony" price="50"/>
            </ItemList>
        </Store>
    </StoreList>
</PCstore>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="type" select="'laptop'"/>
    <xsl:param name="brand" select="'gateway'"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <PCstore>
            <StoreList>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('file:///C:/store_test?select=*.xml')/PCstore/StoreList/Store"/>
            </StoreList>
        </PCstore>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Items[not(@*[name()=$type]=$brand)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<PCstore>
   <StoreList>
      <Store id="001">
            <ItemList>

                <Items laptop="gateway" price="450"/>

            </ItemList>
        </Store>
      <Store id="002">
            <ItemList>
                <Items laptop="gateway" price="650"/>


            </ItemList>
        </Store>
   </StoreList>
</PCstore>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I apologize, I didn´t tried this since i needed to merge for more than 1 xml.

But Im checking the code, and perhaps, It might be useful for the param (brand) to insert in the xml.

Too many thanks.